# How can I copy lines from a file every 60 seconds, and continue from last copied

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, scripting

I need to copy x lines from a file every 60 seconds, and after 60 sec, continue to copy for another 60 sec, restarting from last copied?

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
  sed -n -e '1,10000' input.yml > output.txt 
  sleep 60 
done
```

thanks

Comment: Do you really always want the first 10000 lines? Or rather 1-10000, then 10001-20000, then 20001-30000 and so on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to overwrite `output.txt` in each run:

```
#! /bin/sh -

while true; do
  head -n 10000 > output.txt
  sleep 60
done < input.yml
```

If not:

```
#! /bin/sh -

while true; do
  head -n 10000
  sleep 60
done < input.yml > output.txt
```

Those copy *up to* 10000 lines every 60 seconds. If there aren't that many  lines, it will not wait until there are 10000.

They assume a `head` implementation that leaves the cursor within the input just after the list byte they output. That's a POSIX requirement if the input file is seekable (like when `input.yml` is a *regular* file).

If you wanted to wait for those 10000 lines at each iteration, you could do it (on a GNU system) with:

```
tail -fn+1 input.yml |
  while true; do
    sed -u 10000q > output.txt
    sleep 60
  done
```

Here, the input is a pipe which is not seekable. So we need a `head` implementation that can read one byte at a time until the 10000<sup>th</sup> newline character. Hence GNU `sed` with its `-u` that does just that.

Another approach would be:

```
tail -fn+1 input.yml | awk -v out=output.txt -v n=10000 '
  {print > out}
  NR % n == 0 {close(out); system("sleep 60")}'
```

(if your `awk` is `mawk`, you need to pass `-W interactive`). That one doesn't need to read one byte at a time because it's always the same invocation of the same command that reads the input. Note that `awk` executes a shell each time to run that `sleep 60` command.

Comment: "restarting form last copied" - Are you sure OP wants the same lines or rather the following 10000 line block each time?

Comment: @Fiximan, "restarting from last copied" suggests they want the following lines (which is what my addresses).

Comment: Ah, yes, I misread and though `head` reads the file, not the loop. My bad.