# Monitoring a file and executing a command based on changes to that file

Tags: awk, monitoring, tail

I am searching for a way to execute a command when a keyword appears in a given file, say `temp.txt`. Currently, I have tried `tail -F temp.txt | awk '/keyword/ {echo found}'`. The desired goal is for `echo found` to execute only when a new line is added to `temp.txt` that contains `keyword`. I would like to find the simplest solution with basic commands.

I feel like the answer to this linked post is what I want, but it isn't working for me, and I cant figure out why.

[Best way to follow a log and execute a command when some text appears in the log](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12075/best-way-to-follow-a-log-and-execute-a-command-when-some-text-appears-in-the-log)

Comment: FWIW, that answer doesn't work with mawk (which is default awk on Debian). Try with `tail -F file | awk -Winteractive '/keyword/{system("some_command")}'` or `tail -F | gawk ...`.

Comment: Please provide the error or the exact commands you are running.

Comment: it is the tail and awk command written in the post. im using the macos zsh.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
while :; do awk '/keyword/{print "found"}'; sleep 1; done < temp.txt
```

or if you want to execute a shell command instead of just printing "found":

```
while :; do awk '/keyword/{system("echo \047found\047"}'; sleep 1; done < temp.txt
```

That uses mandatory POSIX commands and will work in any shell on every Unix box. For example:

```
$ echo foo > temp.txt

$ while :; do awk '/keyword/{print "\n>>> found <<<\n"}'; sleep 1; done < temp.txt &
[1] 16520

$ echo keyword >> temp.txt
$
>>> found <<<
```

See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/629912/133219 for more information on that approach.

If "keyword" doesn't appear often in the file and you care about that loop spinning in the background using CPU cycles, you can get a bit fancier with the sleep value by doubling it up to some max value every time through the loop when keyword isn't found so the code spends far more time sleeping than executing, something like this bash code but can be written for any shell:

```
secs=1
maxSecs=60
while :; do
    if awk '/keyword/{print "found"; f=1} END{exit !f}'; then
        secs=1
    else
        if (( (2*secs) < maxSecs )); then
            secs=$(( 2*secs ))
        else
            secs=$maxSecs
        fi
    fi
    sleep "$secs"
done < temp.txt
```

That will run awk once per second while "keyword" is showing up that quickly in your file, and when it's not it'll gradually cycle down to calling awk once per minute until "keyword" starts showing up again and then start calling awk once per second again. Obviously set maxSecs to whatever value you like - 5, 30, 3600, whatever.

Comment: You could use `inotifywait` to get rid of the sleep.

Comment: @lumbric `inotifywait` is not a mandatory POSIX command, it's not even a POSIX-defined utility, see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/idx/utilities.html. It looks like it might be a Linux thing (and the OP is on a Mac, see https://superuser.com/q/371354 for a similar Mac command - thanks google :-)! ) and so wouldn't be portable to all Unix boxes. The OP said they want `the simplest solution with basic commands` and I interpret "basic" as "mandatory POSIX".

Comment: yes, you are right. A busy loop is probably good enough in most situations. Still, avoiding the sleep is a better solution if it is possible because it's faster and more efficient. So I guess there is a trade off, but in practice won't make a difference.

Comment: @lumbric Maybe you missed my point - `inotifywait` is not available on all Unix boxes and is not a "basic" command as I understand the OPs request so there is no trade-off, it's just not a viable solution to this question.